# how to setup multiple language in yii2 in simple way

Tags: php, yii2

I am working on yii2 framework.This is new framework for me. I want to setup multiple language. I tried some way but didn't got success. Can anyone please suggest me simplest way ? What should i have to do ? 
I am using this reference link 
http://techisworld.com/working-with-multiple-languages-app-in-yii2-framework-using-i18n-system.html

Comment: In Yii 1 there was messages folder and you just do `Yii::t('messagesFileName', 'messageKey');`

Comment: #Justinas I did in Yii1 but having issue in Yii2

Comment: What problem you are getting? Is it still showing English version or it is showing key?

Comment: What's the problem? Read this and start coding: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

**1- For dynamic content (coming from database) I usually use this:**

[webvimark/multilanguage](https://github.com/webvimark/multilanguage)

It is very easy and isolated from your app DB tables structure and code, that gives flexibility in adding/removing languages at the long term.

**2- For static content (words inside the markup) in frontend as an example:**

add the lines in your frontend/config/main.php file,

```
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Put you translation file app.php file inside /frontend/messages, as any Yii translation file it returns an array of translations in a key-value pairs.
Then you can translate your static content using:

`Yii::t('app', 'text to be translated')`